# matching a date in a google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to match a date within a google spreadsheet, but I am new to this, and I could use some help.  I have a column that contains a list of birthdays.  I have a cell that I am using to reference for the current date by using

```
=Today()
```

What I would like to do is compare the month and day, but ignore the year, and return the values in the two adjacent columns.  I am using this query to try to get the information.

```
=QUERY(C2:E430; "select * where C = date '" & text(F2,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "'")
```

but it always returns an empty output, because the year never matches.  How do I get it to ignore the year?

Thank you,

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to compare the month and day separately (note that the MONTH() spreadsheet function is January = 1, while the month() function in the QUERY select clause is January = 0).

`=QUERY(C2:E430;"select * where month(C) = "&(MONTH(F2)-1)&" and day(C) = "&DAY(F2))`